# TypeScript inference: Generic type instantiated to something too permissive (null is unioned in)

Tags: typescript, generics

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoCpwMoFMoA8GAfABQDOAXInoSQDSIBuyANiLtRgJTVNwxUiAN4AoRBMTkAdGlSkW7XNwDcogL6jRoSLASJgFarQLkoAJxhgA5sW4jxkuVloVGARlWIA9N8S5zczhzRFJrODhUbkcJZxx8N0QwEFZWL19EADkAeUQAUQAlAuyCgEJEAAMMCsQYclqwM2QwWGQoXCEoOEqzSxtEAB8klNYKjSA)

```js
function addToSet<T>(s: Set<T>, value: T): void {
    s.add(value);
}

function f(s: Set<string>) {
    addToSet(s, 1); // error (good)
    addToSet(s, null); // NO ERROR! `T` is instantiated to `string | null`
}
```

How can I prevent the unsoundness here?  Is there a better way to write `addToSet`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May not the best solution, but it works:

```
function addToSet<T, K extends T>(s: Set<T>, value: K): void {
    s.add(value);
}

function f(s: Set<string>) {
    addToSet(s, 1); // error (good)
    addToSet(s, null); // Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345)
}
```

This forces typescript to infer the generic type from the argument set, and the value has to conform to that generic type.

Note: assuming `"strictNullChecks": true` in tsconfig.json